# MS Power Automate - Won't run until 37 seconds after starting

Tags: microsoft-power-automate-desktop

I'm new to MS Power Automate.  I was trying to use it to enter repetitive data into an application.  I noticed there is a lag between clicking the various menu items in my application.

To duplicate my issue, I opened the calculator app in Windows 11, and I recorded a session where I pressed 2 + 2 =.  When I play this back, the pressing of the buttons occurs in real time speed, but the time from when I press "Run" to the very first "2" button being pressed is 37 seconds.  This happens each time, and it's the same lag I'm seeing when I try to use Power Automate on my application.  In the attached screen shot, you can see the status running is 00:00:33 and nothing has been performed on the calculator yet.  In a couple seconds the button pressing will occur.

Does anyone know why I'm seeing this lag?

Answer (score 0):

There is no screenshot attached to the question. However, if you are using the desktop with Power Automate, there might be a lag due to the fact that you are trying to use a cloud service with a desktop application. This would make it need to use a Gateway, which can often cause slow-downs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).